# How to make M2M items unique

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am creating a `keyword` field for my table items which has to be unique. Now i understand how to make the table items unique, but how do i make the M2M items unique aswell so they are not reused?

Here is the code i have so far:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)

class MainEntity(models.Model): 
    keywords = models.ManyToManyField(Keyword, default=None, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Keyword')
```

So this example works, except the fact that i can create a bunch of other `MainEntity` items which has the same `Keyword`, but obviously i cannot create the duplicate `Keyword` hence its `unique`. But how do i restrict usage of the same keyword?

Comment: What do you mean by "How do i restrict usage of the same keyword"? Smells a little like you want a ForeignKey relationship?

Comment: So basically i need to have a ForeignKey in my `Keyword` that points to `MainEntity`?

Comment: Depends - can a `MainEntity` have more than one `Keyword`?

Comment: It can, basically thats why i chose the M2M approach.. But the same Keyword name cannot be used twice.

Comment: Ever? Or just with a single `MainEntity`?

Comment: With any `MainEntity`.. Once one `Keyword` is used it cannot be reused in another `MainEntity`. The Keyword is used as a alternative name

Comment: I am using the Keyword field to do post-processing of content and creating links in the content  by examining which keywords are connected to which `MainEntity`. Therefor it is critical that each keyword are not duplicated, else i will have conflicts.

Comment: Sorry i made a mistake. Please ignore `i updated the example`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, going to take a stab at the answer. The following ensures you have unique `Keywords`, that can only refer to a single `MainEntity`, but a `MainEntity` can have multiple Keywords:

```
class Keyword(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=False)
    main_entity = models.ForeignKey(MainEntity)

class MainEntity(models.Model):
    ...
```

(I presume `MaintEntity` has other fields that have been stripped for the sake of brevity and you'll replace "..." with those fields ^_^)